# KOMA-script: make chapter number appear underneath the word "Chapter"

Tags: sectioning, koma-script

I want to have the chapter number underneath the word "Chapter" instead of in the same line. I already have them aligned to the right, but don't know where to even start changing the position of the chapter number.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt, twoside, openright,headsepline,chapterprefix=true,toc=indentunnumbered]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[paperheight=24.6cm, paperwidth=17.6cm, inner=2.6cm, outer=1.9cm, top=2.8cm, bottom=2.2cm,footskip=1.3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

%%%---chapter titles added with \chapter are aligned to the right of the page
\newcommand*{\originalchapterlineswithprefixformat}{}
\let\originalchapterlineswithprefixformat\chapterlineswithprefixformat

\renewcommand\chapterlineswithprefixformat[3]{%
    \ifstr{#1}{chapter}
    {\ifstr{#2}{}{\raggedright}{\raggedleft}}
    {}%
    \originalchapterlineswithprefixformat{#1}{#2}{#3}
}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[
afterindent=false,beforeskip=2cm,% afterindent needs version 3.26 or newer
afterskip=20pt,innerskip=12cm
]{chapter}

\addtokomafont{chapter}{\huge\bfseries} 
\addtokomafont{chapterprefix}{\fontsize{90}{76}\selectfont} 

\renewcommand\chapterpagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Introduction}

\end{document}
```

What I have vs. what I want:
[image]

Comment: I am very much aware that this isn't good style. I'm literally asking for a friend.

Comment: Off topic: In KOMA-Script version 3.28 `\ifstr` was replaced by `\Ifstr`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to redefine `\chapterformat`

```latex
\renewcommand*\chapterformat{\chaptername\\*\thechapter}
```